# How horizon dashboard internally fetch the data using AngularJS

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-horizon, openstack-heat

I am New to Open stack. Presently I am try to understand how horizon dashboard internally fetch the data using AngularJS. For example the instance panel under **Compute** DashBoard.How the Instance Name, Image Name, IPAddress, Availability etc fetched from the database.How the following information is coming into table

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Horizon is written using the django framework.   Django is pythonic.

As such the horizon framework can tie directly into the various openstack python client packages.

There is code in horizon that imports things like python-novaclient directly as a module and then makes use of the methods in that client to populate attributes in each component defined in the django framework.

not sure of that answers your question.